# Is 2 a generator of $(\mathbb Z/5^k\mathbb Z)^\times$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If not, is there a $k\ge 1000$, for which it is?

I want to know this, because it will then fit in my proof that there exists a power of $2$ whose last $1000$ digits are either $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES, $2$ is a generator of $G_k=({\mathbb Z}/{5^k}{\mathbb Z})^{\times}$
for every $k\geq 1$.

The order of $G_k$ is $m=\phi(5^k)=4(5^{k-1})$. The only prime divisors of
$m$ are $2$ and $5$. So a $g\in G_k$ generates
$G_k$ iff $g^{{\frac{m}{2}}}\neq 1$ and $g^{{\frac{m}{5}}}\neq 1$, i.e.
$g^{2(5^{k-1})}\neq 1$ and $g^{{4(5^{k-2})}}\neq 1$.

It will suffice to show that for every $k\geq 1$, we have
$$
2^{2(5^{k-1})} \equiv (-1) \ ({\sf mod} \ 5^k),\ \text{and} \
2^{4(5^{k-2})} \equiv (5t_k+1) \ ({\sf mod} \ 5^k) \tag{1}
$$

for some integer $t_k$. Let us show this by induction : for $k=1$, we have

$$
2^{2(5^{1-1})} =4 \equiv (-1) \ ({\sf mod} \ 5) \tag{2}
$$

for $k=2$ we have

$$
2^{2(5^{2-1})}=1024 \equiv (-1) \ ({\sf mod} \ 25),\ \text{and}\
2^{4(5^{2-2})}=16 \equiv (5t_2+1) \ ({\sf mod} \ 25), \ \text{with} \ t_2=3. \tag{3}
$$

So suppose that that (1) is true at level $k\geq 2$, we are going to show that
it is also true at level $k+1$.

We have $2^{2(5^{k-1})}=(-1)+(5^k)x$ for some integer $x$, so
$$2^{2(5^{k})}=\big(5^kx-1\big)^5=
(5^{5k})x^5-(5^{4k+1})x^4+2(5^{3k+1})x^3-2(5^{2k+1})x^2+(5^{k+1})x-1
\equiv (-1) \ ({\sf mod} \ 5^{k+1})
$$
as wished.

Similarly, we can write $2^{4(5^{k-2})}=5t_k+1+5^kx$ for some integer $x$.
Putting $w=5t_k+5^kx$, we have

$$
2^{4(5^{k-1})}=(w+1)^5=w^5 + 5w^4 + 10w^3 + 10w^2 + 5w + 1
$$

but

$$
w=5t_k+5^kx, w^j\equiv (5t_k)^j \ ({\sf mod} \ 5^{k+1}) \ \text{for} \ j\geq 2,
$$

so

$$
2^{4(5^{k-1})}=(w+1)^5=(5t_k)^5 + 5(5t_k)^4 + 10(5t_k)^3 + 10(5t_k)^2 + 5t_k+5^kx + 1
\ ({\sf mod} \ 5^{k+1})
$$

so that we may take

$$
t_{k+1}=5^4t_k^5 + (5t_k)^4 + 2(5t_k)^3 + 2(5t_k)^2 + t_k+5^{k-1}x
$$

and this finishes the proof.